# Excel: Derive Value from Column Without VBA

Tags: excel, range

column `B` is using value `1` based on certain criteria. Now I want to get the first and last value in column `A` having the same algebraic sign (`+` or `-`) as the value of the row with `1` in column `B`.
Example (see yellow markings)

In column `B` value `1` shows up at value `-70,25037`. Now I want to derive `-6,86490` and `-31,42834`as first and last value with `-` algebraic sign same as algebraic sign of `-70,25037`.

I can not use VBA code. Any suggestions?

Thanks al lot!

[image]

Comment: Can you use Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365), or must you use formulas.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thanks a lot. Unfortunaltely I can not use Power Query. I need to use formulas.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Can you explain why you do not wish to return the other range of positive values on the first value of 1?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, it is Office 365, Version 2008

Comment: @JvdV, it will need to return the range for the first `1` as well. The highlighted yellow area is only to show the example. At the end I need to find a formula which work for all `1` indicated values in column `B`, for positive and negantive values/range in column `B`.

Answer (score 1):

One method:

Add a helper column to detect the signChange.

I chose column E, but it could be anyplace

```
E2: 0
E3: =IF(SIGN(A3)=SIGN(A2),E2,E2+1)
```

*and fill down to bottom of table*

You don't show how you want to display the results. In my example, the results are displayed in the two columns on the same row as where `Bn=1`

```
F2: =TRANSPOSE(IF(B2=1,LET(x,FILTER($A:$A,$E:$E=E2),rws,ROWS(x),INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(2,,1,rws-1))),""))
```

*and fill down to bottom of table*

[image]